# Spark SQL - collect distinct string values

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column `colors`, which stores comma delimited color names.
In the output I need to have a string consisting of comma separated distinct color names (grouped by `id` column). Note: I need to have this in **Spark SQL**.

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT id, concat_ws(', ', sort_array( collect_set(colors))) as csv_colors
FROM ( 
  VALUES ('A', 'green'),('A','yellow'),('A','yellow, green, blue'),('B', 'blue'),('B','green') 
) as T (id, colors)
GROUP BY id
""").toPandas()
```

What I am getting is:

```
id  csv_colors
0   B   blue, green
1   A   green, yellow, yellow, green, blue
```

What I need is:

```
id  csv_colors
0   B   blue, green
1   A   blue, green, yellow
```

I'd appreciate any hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split and explode the colors first:

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT id, concat_ws(', ', sort_array(collect_set(colors))) as csv_colors 
FROM (
    SELECT id, explode(split(colors, ', ')) colors
    FROM ( 
        VALUES ('A', 'green'),('A','yellow'),('A','yellow, green, blue'),('B', 'blue'),('B','green') 
    ) as T (id, colors)
)
GROUP BY id
""")

+---+-------------------+
| id|         csv_colors|
+---+-------------------+
|  B|        blue, green|
|  A|blue, green, yellow|
+---+-------------------+
```